# Auto updating fields with default values in DB after persisting using dynamicInsert

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have a table

```
  CREATE TABLE "PEOPLE" (
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(40 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    "SURNAME" VARCHAR2(40 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    "FATHER_NAME" VARCHAR2(40 CHAR),
    "IS_RETIRED" CHAR(1 CHAR) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL
  );
```

I have annotated it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PEOPLE")
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
public class Person {

   public enum YesNo {
      Y, N;
   }

   public Person(String name, String surname) {
       this.name = name;
       this.surname = surname;
   }

   @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 40)
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "SURNAME", nullable = false, length = 40)
   private String surname;

   @Column(name = "FATHER_NAME", length = 40)
   private String fatherName;

   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   @Column(name = "IS_RETIRED", nullable = false)
   private YesNo isRetired;

   ... // simple getter and setter for each field
}
```

I want to run code:

```
...
Peson person = new Person ("John", "Smith");
entityManager.persist(person);
... // diffrent operations, end of old transaction, begin of new
person.setFatherName("Peter");
entityManager.update(person);
```

I got error:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01407: cannot update (???) to NULL
```

It seems that despite giving default value in DB, after persisting value of field isRetired of object person is still null. When I try to perform dynamic update on person, hibernate wants to change saved value in DB ('N') to null. Is there a way to automatically update value of fields with default values after dynamic insert? Is it possible to perform it without hardcoding default values in class definitions in Java (if I change default value in database, I don't want to have to do the same in Java code)?

Comment: JUst remove *nullable = false*

Comment: It doesn't help. Value of field "isRetired" is still null and hibernate tries to set value of column in DB to null which leads to raise of exception.

Comment: If I understand correctly, after persisting the `person` object the value of the `IS_RETIRED` column in the database is set to 'N', but in-memory the value of the `isRetired` attribute of the object is still NULL. Sounds to me like you should re-fetch the values of the `person` object from the database so the two are in sync, or set `isRetired` to 'N' (No) before calling `persist`. Basically, you're counting on "hidden" behavior in the database to set an attribute in memory which the database knows nothing about, and apparently Hibernate isn't doing this automagically. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the javadocs for `@DynamicUpdate` it seems like they key point is "for re-attachment of detached entities this is not possible without select-before-update being enabled."

So, my guess is it worked fine for the insert, but not for the update because it is a detached entity from a prior transaction.